# Can I do an arithmetic operation on rows in the SQL Server query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT MATRICULE,ID_POINTAGE,DT_POINTAGE,HH_POINTAGE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(SS,HH_POINTAGE,8),108) GMT,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MATRICULE,DT_POINTAGE ORDER BY MATRICULE , DT_POINTAGE) AS NEMRA,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MATRICULE,DT_POINTAGE ORDER BY MATRICULE , DT_POINTAGE) % 2 = 1 THEN 'S' ELSE 'E' END ENTREE_SORTIE FROM POINTAGES WHERE MATRICULE = '0118' AND DT_POINTAGE = '30/10/2019'AND HH_POINTAGE NOT IN ((SELECT MAX(HH_POINTAGE) FROM POINTAGES WHERE MATRICULE = '0118' AND DT_POINTAGE = '30/10/2019'),(SELECT MIN(HH_POINTAGE) FROM POINTAGES WHERE MATRICULE = '0118' AND DT_POINTAGE = '30/10/2019'))

--Formatted Query
SELECT MATRICULE,
       ID_POINTAGE,
       DT_POINTAGE,
       HH_POINTAGE,
       CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SS, HH_POINTAGE, 8), 108) AS GMT,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATRICULE, DT_POINTAGE ORDER BY MATRICULE, DT_POINTAGE) AS NEMRA,
       CASE
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATRICULE, DT_POINTAGE ORDER BY MATRICULE, DT_POINTAGE) % 2 = 1 THEN 'S'
            ELSE 'E'
       END AS ENTREE_SORTIE
FROM POINTAGES
WHERE MATRICULE = '0118'
  AND DT_POINTAGE = '30/10/2019'
  AND HH_POINTAGE NOT IN ((SELECT MAX(HH_POINTAGE)
                           FROM POINTAGES
                           WHERE MATRICULE = '0118'
                             AND DT_POINTAGE = '30/10/2019'), (SELECT MIN(HH_POINTAGE)
                                                               FROM POINTAGES
                                                               WHERE MATRICULE = '0118'
                                                                 AND DT_POINTAGE = '30/10/2019'));
```

I get these results:

[image]

My question is if there is any way I can do the following operation on the `HH_POINTAGE` column:  `(32820 - 32400) + (42000 - 41400) + (50400 - 43200)`

Comment: Yes. There is a way, but you will have to add another query. What's the logic here? Why some numbers are added and other subtracted?

Comment: The values represente time in seconds , The GMT is the time , it's the in and outs of an employee during a day, i want to know his presence during the day so it's 09:07 - 09:00  thats 7 minutes +  (11:40 - 11:30 thats 10 minutes) etc .....

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want this based on the even/oddness of `nemra`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select sum(case when nemra % 2 = 1 then hh_pointage
                else - hh_pointage
           end)
from t;
```